# Add element to PHP associative array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked but can't find an answer for my specific use case. I want to add an element to a multidimensional array while looping through it. What I have before the loop:

```
Array
(
    [fname] => Monty
    [lname] => Python
    [phone] => 555 555 1212
    [email] => a@b.com
    [modelList] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [modelName] => X-Wing
                    [remarks] => 
                    [htmlRemarks] => 
                    [category] => Vehicles
                    [catID] => 178
                    [attachedToBase] => 1
                    [oversized] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

In code, I'm looping through the [modelList] array and after doing some database operations what I want to do is append new elements to each model array - in the case below, the [dbID]:

```
Array
(
    [fname] => Monty
    [lname] => Python
    [phone] => 555 555 1212
    [email] => a@b.com
    [modelList] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [modelName] => X-Wing
                    [remarks] => 
                    [htmlRemarks] => 
                    [category] => Vehicles
                    [catID] => 178
                    [attachedToBase] => 1
                    [oversized] => 0
                    [dbID] => 907
                )

        )

)
```

All inputs are from a form POST, and in my php handler:

```
// Loop thru model entries
$modelList = json_decode($_POST["modelList"], TRUE); 
foreach($modelList as $model) {

    (do some work)

    // Add the new element
    array_push($model['dbID'], $newID);
}
```

But this throws an error:

```
PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

How can I add the new element to the sub-array?

Comment: your error is not related to your problem. and for your problem, anyone can tell you that you should use references. but check this document and more dive into it. I think it's worth it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - I needed to use a reference to $model in order to update it

```
// Loop thru model entries
$modelList = json_decode($_POST["modelList"], TRUE); 
foreach($modelList as &$model) {

    (do some work)

    // Add the new element
    $model['dbID'] = $newID;
}
unset($model);
```

Answer (score 1):

[**array_push**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

> Push one or more elements onto the end of array

You can't add a key value item to an array using `array_push`.
Use this instead :

```
foreach ($modelList as $key => $model){
  $modelList[$key]['dbID'] = $newID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet with the loop are you trying to actually *update* the `dbID`?

If so, you should change the logic to:

```php
foreach ($modelList as $key => $model) {

    (do some work)
   
    $modelList[$key]['dbID'] = $newID;
}
```

Why:

- you cannot change contents of the array you are looping over (unless accessed by reference)
- in your example code `$model['dbID']` is number `907` which is not an array, hence the error message

Comment: I found the answer just after you posted - I need to access the array by reference. And I'm not updating dbID; I'm adding it to the existing sub-array.

Comment: @NCC1701 Well both the solution you found and the one I suggest lead to the same result. I am glad you found your solution. But watch out, doing things like this using by-reference access can lead to code that is harder to manage.